# active model serializer multiple collection in one template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have this custom action which I want to save http trips to retrieve different collections with.

```
def dashboard
  @projects = Project.all
  @tasks    = Task.all

  respond_do do |format|
    format.json {render {projects: @project, tasks: @tasks}, serializer: DashboardSerializer }
  end
end

class DashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :proejcts, :tasks

end
```

this gives me an error like this

```
 undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Hash:0x007fb5d58108c0>
```

Is there any way that I can make arbitrary collection attributes in the active model serializer template as I can do in Rabl?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AMS has a distinction between single item serialization and item collection serialization.

I was getting the same error, my solution looked like this:

```
 render json: @posts, each_serializer: FancyPostSerializer
```